# Add a reaction to a message in an interaction

Tags: python, discord, nextcord

I have a poll command in my nextcord bot. I want to add reactions, but when I try the command, It give me this: `https://imgur.com/a/p6s3yy5` . How can i fix it?

btw, this is my command:

```py
@nextcord.slash_command(name="yes-no-poll", description="Crée un sondage à deux options", guild_ids=[server])
async def yesno(self, ctx: nextcord.Interaction, poll):
    embed = nextcord.Embed(title=poll, color=nextcord.Color.blue())
    vote = await ctx.response.send_message(embed=embed)
    await vote.add_reaction("<:yes:914969003645091900>")
    await vote.add_reaction("<:no:914969105482809355>")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please refrain from posting your errors as images. Please paste them directly into the post.

### Explanation

As for the code at hand, `InteractionResponse.send_message()` always returns `None`, unlike `abc.Messageable.send()`, which returns a `nextcord.Message`.

This of course raises an Exception when you try to call `add_reaction` on a `NoneType`.

To get around this, you can search the `Interaction.channel` for a message containing the same Embed as the one you just sent, then add the reaction to that.

### Code

```py
@nextcord.slash_command(name="yes-no-poll", description="Crée un sondage à deux options", guild_ids=[703732969160048731])
async def yesno(self, ctx: nextcord.Interaction, poll):
    embed = nextcord.Embed(title=poll, colour=nextcord.Colour.blue())
    await ctx.response.send_message(embed=embed)

    # Loop through channel history and pull the message that matches (should be first)
    message: nextcord.Message
    async for message in ctx.channel.history():
        if not message.embeds:
            continue
        if message.embeds[0].title == embed.title and message.embeds[0].colour == embed.colour:
            vote = message
            break
    else:
        # something broke
        return

    await vote.add_reaction("<:yes:914969003645091900>")
    await vote.add_reaction("<:no:914969105482809355>")
```